# Filtering Sharepoint 2013 Search results based on Authentication

Tags: search-results, sharepoint-server, authentication

Sharepoint 2013 Search

I have External data from DB in search and it provides many search results.

I have to refine this search results based on user's authentication. Is it possible? Share your ideas.

Comment: Do you really mean "refine" as in further filter, or do you mean "security trim" the results based on the users permissions?

Comment: Dont know how to implement security trim. ya I want the results based on users permission(Security trim).If not possible atleast I should be able to refine the search results.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement crawl time security trimming in your BCS connector by implementing the BinarySecurityDescriptorAccessor method. This is documented on MSDN: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg294169(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg294169%28v=office.15%29.aspx)